# Difference between sudo /bin/bash and sudo su to access root

Tags: bash, ubuntu-14.04, sudo

I am aware that there are at least 2 ways to escalate to root privileges when in the terminal, and am genuinely curious as to whether there is a differences / are differences as to what can be accessed or not in either. Also, are the any security benefits or drawbacks in either?

Comment: like the useless use of cat, sudo su is like a useless use of sudo.  I generally use sudo -s if I really really need to get a root shell and never use su.

Comment: What's the reasoning behind not wanting to use su?

Comment: @VignshSankaran - sudo allows you to run commands as another user - usually root.  su gives you a root shell or a shell as another user.  Essentially they achieve the same thing, but in different ways.  Sudo is far superior to su.  If you just want a root shell, run sudo -s.

Comment: @VigneshSankaran: Essentially, `sudo su` means "switch to root, then switch to root again in a slightly different way." If you wanted to be even more redundant, you could use `su root -c 'sudo su'`.

Answer (score 2):

`su` is used to authenticate to a 2nd user using the credentials of the 2nd user.

`sudo` is used to authenticate to another user using some rules written in the sudo configuration file `/etc/sudoers`. To make sure that you are how you pretend to be, `sudo` can ask for your credentials again.

`sudo` is more flexible allowing administrators to give access to some scripts  commands or edit files in a secure and limited way.

`su` is not that flexible and required to know the credentials of the user you want to impersonate. Because it has a simple function, it is very small and found on almost all Unix like systems.

Both `su` and `sudo` are using [Linux-PAM](http://www.linux-pam.org/) for authentication. Some distributions even have different PAM configuration for `sudo` compared to `su`.  So I had to use `sudo su` to be able to apply the limits but also use `sudo` for authentication.

Here is my PAM config for an Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, highlighting the differences between `su` and `sudo` PAM configs:

```
$ diff -y <(egrep -v '^#|^$' /etc/pam.d/su|sort) <(egrep -v '^#|^$' /etc/pam.d/sudo|sort)
auth       sufficient pam_rootok.so                           <
@include common-account                                         @include common-account
@include common-auth                                            @include common-auth
@include common-session                                       | @include common-session-noninteractive
session    optional   pam_mail.so nopen                       | session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/defau
session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1                 | session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/de <
session    required   pam_limits.so                           <
$
```

In general the literature encourages to use `sudo` instead of `su`, in this way you do not need another set of passwords that you might need to share. But in practice you might find yourself in the position where you need `su` too or even both of them.

Learn, test, read the docs and use the best one for your case.

Now some examples of how to use them:

```
sudo fdisk -l     # List all disk MS-DOS and GPT partitions
su -c 'fdisk -l'  # same as above
sudo -i           # Become root
su -              # same as above
sudo bash         # Run a bash shell as root in the current folder, and keep the environment variables
su bash           # same as above
sudo -u oracle ps # Run ps as oracle user
su oracle ps      # same as above
sudo su -         # you should use: sudo -i
sudo -iu oracle   # Start a login shell as oracle user
su - oracle       # same as above
```

Besides `su` and `sudo`, on Linux you can find [polkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polkit) which has `pkexec`. For more details see [polkit documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/).
Example:

```
pkexec fdisk -l # It's similar to: sudo fdisk -l
```

Answer (score 0):

a quick inspection  of the man pages will show that `sudo` is used primarily to launch commands as another user, while `su` is used to "substitute user credentials", via PAM.  The man pages have more in depth info about what specifically happens when commands are executed using `su` and `sudo`.

Comment: While I know that self research is important, the gist of me asking the question was to gain an understanding via a summary. I'm afraid this answer doesn't provide that.